# Why people use <object classid=""> to show PDF instead of src="1.pdf"

Tags: html, pdf

What's the difference?

Comment: Where are you even seeing this?

Answer (score 3):

The object tag is to embed the PDF inside the browser, so the user can browse the PDF content inside the browser.

The normal link would force the user to download the pdf and read it with an another software.